# What does "error: cannot use type 'void' as a range" actually mean?

Tags: c++, clang

When I compile this in clang 3.2

```
for(auto x : {1, 1.2}){}
```

I get an error like this:

> error: cannot use type 'void' as a range

What does it mean?

Answer (score 17):

You mixed your types in the initializer list. In this case it can be pretty clear, but don't forget

```
std::string foo;
for(auto x : {foo, "bar"}){}
```

Are also 2 separate types. There are of course plenty of other cases where you may expect it to work, but the types have to match exactly.